# Javascript document.title doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, title

I'm using Safari 6.0.5.

I open a new empty window, try to change the title to 'debug window', nothing happens. With a check function checking every 10 milliseconds, it says the window.document.title is 'Debug Window', still the new Window title bar says it is 'untitled'.

```
var debug_window    =   window.open('', 'debug_window', 'height=200'); 

debug_window.document.title     =   'Debug Window';

    function check() 
    {

    debugLog(1, 'title:' + debug_window.document.title);
    if(debug_window.document) { // if loaded
        debug_window.document.title = "debug_window"; // set title
    } else { // if not loaded yet
        setTimeout(check, 10); // check in another 10ms
    }
     }
     check();
```

The output in the debugLog is:

```
17:35:04.558: title:
17:35:04.584: title:debug_window
```

What is going wrong here that the new window is still called 'untitled'?

Thanks!

Comment: `debug_window.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Debug Window";` ;) or first create title element and then append it

Comment: Try this... http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/93QFk/

Comment: @Givi, it still says untitled at your link...

Comment: My own code works in Chrome, it is Safari that is bugging me; Your code works too in Chrome. Thnx!

Comment: Yes probably, there some bugs in Safari. It's pity, that it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Now the second argument to window.open() is a frame/window-name and serves also as the default title. This is eventually overridden by the document loaded into this window. Opening the document-stream and inserting a basic html-document should serve the purpose:</strike>

```
var debug_window  = window.open('', 'debug_window', 'height=200');
debug_window.document.open();
debug_window.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<title>Debug Window</title>\n</head>\n<body></body>\n</html>');
debug_window.document.close();

var debug_body = debug_window.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
// write to debug_window
debug_body.innerHTML = '<p>Message</p>';
```

So you would be setting up a basic document inside the window, just as it would be loaded by the server (by writing to the "document stream"). Then you would start to manipulate this document like any other.

---

Edit: Does not work in Safari either.

Other suggestion: set up a basic document (including the title) on the server and inject the   content into its body on load. As a bonus, you may setup CSS via stylesheets.

```
var debug_window  = window.open('debug_template.html', 'debug_window', 'height=200');
debug_window.onload = function() {
  var debug_body = debug_window.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  debug_body.innerHTML = '...';
  // or
  // var el = document.createElement('p');
  // p.innerHTML = '...';
  // debug_body.appendChild(p);
  debug_window.onload=null; // clean up cross-reference
};
```

And on the server side something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Debug Window</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="debug_styles.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

If this still should not work (e.g.: writing to the debug-window's document is without effect), you could call your app from inside the debug-window by something like:

```
<body onload="if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) window.opener.debugCallback(window, window.document);">
</body>
```

(So you would check if the opener – your App – exists and hasn't been closed in the meantime and then call a callback-function "debugCallback()" in your app with the debug-window and its document as arguments.)

Comment: Thank you, your code works in Chrome, but not in Safari. Probably Safari is the bottle neck...

Comment: Just tried this myself, Safari seems to be a special breed here. Inspecting the title via DOM shows the correct title, but it does not show up in the window's title bar. – You may try to load a document with the basic HTML (including the title) and inject your content into its body as soon as it has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var debug_window = window.open('about:blank', 'debug_window', 'height=200');
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.